# Зачем нужны закладки?

Tags: обсуждение, закладки

Зачем на SO нужны закладки, если есть отслеживание поста?

<sub>Сравнение закладок и отслеживания</sub>

```
┌─────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Свойство    │ Закладки              │ Отслеживание              │ Преимущество у…*    │
╞═════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ Уведомления │ Есть                  │ Есть                      │ Нет                 │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Цели        │ Вопросы               │ Вопросы, ответы и метки   │ Отслеживание        │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Анонимность │ Нет                   │ Есть                      │ Отслеживание        │
│             │                       │                           │ (по моему мнению)   │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ UI          │ - Заголовок           │ - Заголовок               │ Нет                 │
│             │ - Кол-во просмотров   │ - Кол-во просмотров       │                     │
│             │ - Разница голосов     │ - Разница голосов         │                     │
│             │ - Кол-во ответов      │ - Кол-во ответов          │                     │
│             │ - Решён ли вопрос     │ - Решён ли вопрос         │                     │
│             │ - Метки               │ - Метки                   │                     │
│             │ - Автор               │ - Автор                   │                     │
│             │ - Реп. автора         │ - Реп. автора             │                     │
│             │ - Разница тек. даты и │ - Разница тек. даты и     │                     │
│             │ даты задания вопроса  │ даты задания вопроса      │                     │
│             │ - Кнопка «Убрать из   │ - Кнопка «Не отслеживать» │                     │
│             │ закладок»             │ - Тип поста               │                     │
│             │ - Кол-во закладок     │                           │                     │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Кнопка      │ - В виде закладки     │ - Текст «Отслеживать»     │ Закладки            │
│             │ - Изменяет цвет, если │ - Изменяет текст, если    │ (незначительное)    │
│             │ добавить в закладки   │ начать отслеживать        │                     │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Событие     │ - Сообщение о         │ - Сообщение о             │ Отслеживание        │
│ нажатия     │ результате нажатия    │ результате нажатия        │ (полезно новичкам)  │
│             │                       │ - Справка о механике      │                     │
│             │                       │ отслеживания              │                     │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Размер UI   │ Отн. маленький        │ Отн. большой              │ Нет                 │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Сортировка  │ - Голоса              │ - Голоса                  │ Закладки            │
│             │ - Активность          │ - Активность              │ (незначительное)    │
│             │ - Новые               │ - Новые                   │                     │
│             │ - Добавлены           │ - Добавлены               │                     │
│             │ - Просмотры           │                           │                     │
├─────────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Метки на SO │ - ruSO: есть          │ - ruSO: нет               │ Закладки            │
│             │ - enSO: есть          │ - enSO: есть              │ (незначительное     │
│             │                       │                           │ (будут вопросы по   │
│             │                       │                           │ отслеживанию –      │
│             │                       │                           │ добавят и на ruSO)) │
└─────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

<sup>* (преимущество может быть *незначительным*: это значит, что оно не оказывает значимого перевеса по сравнению с конкурентом)</sup>

Как мы видим, ничья – 3:3, но если учесть, что преимущества закладок все до единого незначительны, то 3:0 – полный разгром, а если ещё и дотянуть уровень UI, добавить новый фильтр для сортировки, а также добавить соответствующую метку на metaSO, то это безоговорочная сухая (я не говорю, что это нужно делать).

Так зачем нужны эти закладки? Почему в SO 2 вида отслеживания постов?

Comment: Лично я использую "отслеживать", когда интересны комментарии или правки к вопросу/ответу, а закладки для более "long-term" вопросов, на которые интересны каноничные ответы, а не обсуждение в комментариях. Например, могу поставить минус на вопрос и временно отслеживать его, не сделал ли автор правку. Через время очищаю список отслеживаемых. В закладки такой вопрос не добавляю :)

Comment: @dIm0n т. е. закладки – это добавил и забыл, а отслеживание – это добавил и почистил, когда не нужно (не нужно отслеживание, разумеется)?

Comment: Да, но не утверждаю, что такое разделение сделано именно для этого :)

Answer (score 6):

1. В закладки можно добавлять не только вопросы, на которые ты хочешь узнать ответ.
2. В закладки можно добавлять не только хорошие вопросы.
3. Если я добавляю в закладки какой-то забавный вопрос, это вовсе не означает, что я хочу знать о каждом комментарии и ответе, который к нему напишут.
4. Если добавляется какой-то канонический вопрос, то мне он нужен, чтобы кого-то туда отправлять, а не чтобы узнавать об обновлениях в нём.
5. Если я понял и могу воспроизвести решение сам, то вполне вероятно, что в закладки я его добавил вообще с какой-то другой целью.
6. А удалённые вопросы отслеживать можно? И зачем?
7. Закладки намного старше. Отслеживание - это небольшое перерождение фичи из команд, которое заодно прикрутили к остальным сайтам.

Answer (score 0):

**Кратко и понятно:**

Когда вы добавляете вопрос в "закладки", то он просто лежит у вас в "закладках", и вам **не будут приходить уведомления**, если в вопросе будет какая-то активность. А если вы будете "отслеживать" вопос, то вам посыпится куча уведомлений, если в нём будет кипеть жизнь.